# Connect IBM MQ using Node JS

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq

I am connecting IBM MQ from application as client using below Node JS script.

```
var mq = require('ibmmq');
var MQC = mq.MQC;

var qMgr = "QM1";
var hConn;

function formatErr(err) {
  return  "MQ call failed in " + err.message;
}

function cleanup(hConn) {
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    setTimeout(resolve,ms);
  });
}

console.log("Sample AMQSCONN.JS start");

var cno = new mq.MQCNO();

var csp = new mq.MQCSP();
csp.UserId = "mqguest";
csp.Password = "passw0rd";
cno.SecurityParms = csp;

cno.Options |= MQC.MQCNO_CLIENT_BINDING;
var cd = new mq.MQCD();
cd.ConnectionName = "hostname(1435)";
cd.ChannelName = "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN";
cno.ClientConn = cd;

if (MQC.MQCNO_CURRENT_VERSION >= 7) {
  cno.ApplName = "Node.js 9.1.2 ApplName";
}

mq.Connx(qMgr, cno, function(err,conn) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(formatErr(err));
  } else {
    console.log("MQCONN to %s successful ", qMgr);
    sleep(3 *1000).then(() => {
      mq.Disc(conn, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(formatErr(err));
        } else {
          console.log("MQDISC successful");
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

IBM MQ Version : 9.2.0.11

Linux : Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.4 (Ootpa)

Even though i am trying to connect using username and password, It is taking application user name (only exist in Linux not in LDAP) which doesn't have access to MQ.

Getting below error from client side:

CONNX: MQCC = MQCC_FAILED [2] MQRC = MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN[2009]

In MQ error log:

Authorization failed because the SID for entity 'user' cannot be obtained.

If i run this script as different user who has access to MQ, it works fine. Please advise on this.

Even though i am trying to connect using username and password, It is taking application user name (only exist in Linux not in LDAP) which doesn't have access to MQ.

If i run this script as different user who has access to MQ, it works fine. Please advise on this.

Comment: Please show the definition of the AUTHINFO object referred to in your queue manager's CONNAUTH field. I suspect it has the ADOPTCTX attribute set to NO. Sounds like you need to change it to YES (and then refresh or recycle the qmgr),

Comment: @MoragHughson our IT team created Channel Authentication Records for the Queue Manager Channel (SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN) to application user. If i run standalone script (mentioned above) to connect MQ as application user then i can able to connect to MQ. But the same script if i trigger from application as application user then it is not working.

Comment: @MoragHughson I am new to IBM MQ. Can you help me how to check ADOPTCTX attribute value and set it?

Comment: Use runmqsc program to issue DISPLAY QMGR CONNAUTH command. Then take the name of the object shown there and issue DISPLAY AUTHINFO(name-from-connauth-field) ALL and edit your answer to show results. Also show the CHLAUTH rules that apply too if you can: DISPLAY CHLAUTH('*') ALL